# SQLiteException: error code 5: database is locked. When accessing ContentProvider from AsyncTask

Tags: android

Quite frequently I get the following exception and I'm really entirely sure what to do about it.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: error code 5: database is locked
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:61)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.delete(SQLiteDatabase.java:1704)
    at azurewing.android.db.provider.NotificationProvider.delete(NotificationProvider.java:80)
    at azurewing.android.db.provider.Provider.delete(Provider.java:87)
    at azurewing.android.db.provider.NotificationProvider.delete(NotificationProvider.java:1)
    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.delete(ContentProvider.java:234)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:692)
    at azurewing.android.db.table.NotificationTable.removeAllNotifications(NotificationTable.java:89)
    at azurewing.android.sync.SyncReceiver$1$1.doInBackground(SyncReceiver.java:52)
    at azurewing.android.sync.SyncReceiver$1$1.doInBackground(SyncReceiver.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
    ... 4 more
```

I am accessing a ContentProvider (NotificationProvider here) via an AsyncTask. The ContentProvider uses a database of course.

```
@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs)
{
    SQLiteDatabase  db = database.getWritableDatabase();
    int numDeleted = database.delete(NotificationTable.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
    return numDeleted;
}
```

I'm a bit stumped about what to do here. It's clearly a threading issue I think, so I'm thinking of everytime I get the database, I do it from a synchronized method in 1 class. Is this a good idea?

Comment: Did you happen to use `android:process` somewhere in your manifest?

Comment: Just searched. No I didn't have that anywhere in the manifest.

Comment: Are you using more than one instance of your `SQLiteOpenHelper`? Perhaps one by the `ContentProvider` and one elsewhere?

Comment: I have a helper abstract Provider class which has an instance of my SQLiteOpenHelper. I have 4 providers, which will mean multiple instances of the provider will exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either:

- Consolidate those to be one provider with one `SQLiteOpenHelper`, comparing the `Uri` values to see which set of logic to go through, or
- Create four separate databases, one per provider/`SQLiteOpenHelper`, or
- Have a singleton `SQLiteOpenHelper` that all four providers share

SQLite threading in Android is managed by `SQLiteDatabase`. You need exactly one instance of a `SQLiteDatabase` that all threads share for this to work. If you are using `SQLiteOpenHelper`, this usually means that you use exactly one instance of `SQLiteOpenHelper`, since it wraps the `SQLiteDatabase`.

Comment: Fantastic.. I'm sure this is the reason why. I'll come back and accept the question once I've coded it all. Do you think that there is any advantage for creating a separate database for each provider? (My providers all map to tables really)

Comment: @Amorgos: "Do you think that there is any advantage for creating a separate database for each provider?" -- I'd say it's a disadvantage, particularly if you want to offer any sort of a backup mechanism. I just listed it as a candidate solution.

Comment: I understand, but could potentially be a solution if for some reason you really do need separate SQLiteDatabase instances. But I don't.

Comment: I've now created a singleton for my SQLiteOpenHelper instance for all Provider instances. And I'm assuming that SQLiteOpenHelper instance will handle the singleton wrapping for the SQLiteDatabase instance? So now I'm opening and closing that same db instance in all provider methods and also in multiple threads (with an AsyncTask). Is this safe now do you think?

Comment: @Amorgos: That certainly sounds better.

Comment: @CommonsWare.. I mean is it safe to go HelperSingleton.instance().getReadableDatabase() use it and close() it etc. at the same time in 2 threads?

Comment: @Amorgos: **Don't close it** (which you shouldn't be doing anyway, if you wrapping the database with `ContentProviders`). Using it across N threads should be fine, though -- if you look at the source code to `SQLiteDatabase`, you'll see that thread protections are in place there.